# If If iframe is not good to use then is there any other standard complaint way to get same thing like iframe?

Tags: xhtml, w3c

If iframe is not good to use then is there any other standard complaint way to get same thing like iframe?

Answer (score 1):

If something gives you the same results as iframe, then for practical purposes *it is iframe* and thus not good too :)

If you could tell what exactly are you trying to achieve..?